# Skip text input value when calculating the VAT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple script which calculates the VAT:

```
<script>
      function count(){
      price = document.getElementById("price").value;            
      vat = document.getElementById("vat").value;            
      total = price*(1+vat/100);                                    
      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML=total;           
      }
</script>

<input size="20" MAXLENGTH="20" id="price" name="price" type="text" value="" onkeyup="count();">

<select id="vat" onchange="count();">
<option VALUE="22">22 %</option>
<option VALUE="7">7 %</option>
<option VALUE="33">33 %</option>
<option VALUE="ZW">ZW</option>
</select>

<span id="total"></span>
```

[Here is how this script](https://jsfiddle.net/j7b6jnvw/)

I want to do to the script, when I will choose from the selection list the value of a text (eg. "ZW"), then the script to ignore this value and the result showed only entered value in the field.

Comment: `if(isNaN(price)){...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function count(){
  price = document.getElementById("price").value;  
  vat = document.getElementById("vat").value;    
  
  if (isNaN(vat))
    total=price;
  else
    total = price*(1+vat/100);
  
  
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML=total;           
}
```

```html
<input size="20" MAXLENGTH="20" id="price" name="price" type="text" value="" onkeyup="count();">

<select id="vat" onchange="count();">
<option VALUE="22">22 %</option>
<option VALUE="7">7 %</option>
<option VALUE="33">33 %</option>
<option VALUE="ZW">ZW</option>
</select>

<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: Dziękuję bardzo serdecznie Maćku! :)

Comment: Nie ma problemu Rafał, zaznacz jeszcze jako prawidłową odpowiedź. Dzięki i pozdrawiam.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to replace:

```
<option VALUE="ZW">ZW</option>
```

with:

```
<option VALUE="0">ZW</option>
```

This way, all options are consistent with each other. And that would save yourself a specific test where you don't really need one.

```js
function count(){
  price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
  vat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("vat").value);
  total = price*(1+vat/100);
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML=total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input size="20" MAXLENGTH="20" id="price" name="price" type="text" value="" onkeyup="count();">

<select id="vat" onchange="count();">
<option VALUE="22">22 %</option>
<option VALUE="7">7 %</option>
<option VALUE="33">33 %</option>
<option VALUE="0">ZW</option>
</select>

<span id="total"></span>
```